# CronJob Not running

Tags: 20.04, scripts, python, cron, django

I have prepared a py Script to update my Django database once a day. Trying to use Crontab along with python to run the py script.

```
0 1 * * 4 /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder1/script1.py
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder1/folder11/script2.py
```

Crontab is able to run the first script without any problem.
But it's not able to run the second script.

I can able to execute the second py script via the python venv environment without any error

How to read the error of this cronjob?
Anyone experienced this problem, How did you solved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should redirect both standard input and standard error from the crontab execution like below:

```
0 2 * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/user/folder1/folder11/script2.py > /tmp/script2.log 2>&1
```

Then once its failed to run have a look at the /tmp/script2.log for the reason(s).